# Where on earth can I book fun dive with hot water suit?

Tags: where-on-earth, diving

Is there a place on earth which offers hot water suits for tourists?

I like watching Bering Sea Gold, and I'd like to experience how it is to dive in ice cold water with hot water suit. But for fun, as a tourist. Is there a scuba diving center that offers such experience?

Comment: Do you have any diving qualifications? Even for regular dry suit diving, reputable operators should require or teach a dry suit certification course (which first requires open water certification) before taking tourists into freezing cold water.

Comment: Y-40 in Italy offers a 40m deep dive in a thermal hot water pool...but using a normal suit (or bare-chested).

Answer (score 9):

I can't prove a negative, but I got diving certified in a very cold country where ice diving with dry suits is common, and **I've never heard of recreational hot water suit diving**.

Unlike regular wetsuits and drysuits, a hot water suit requires an umbilical cord connected to a support ship capable of dependably supplying the hot water.  This makes the ship itself a part of the diver's life-critical support system, and places diving with one squarely in the realm of commercial diving.  Buoyancy control, movement etc are also considerably complicated by litres of water sloshing around *inside* your suit plus the risk of getting tangled up in the umbilical.  All in all, it's very much an advanced diving technique and not something you can or should attempt without extensive training.

Comment: I’d also note that you’re plenty warm in a dry suit, except for your head. Sadly diving with a diving helmet is also in the realm of pro divers so there’s no way for a casual tourist to experience cold water diving in full comfort.